# Bluetooth Problems

Tags: linux, kali-linux, bluetooth

I have a Kali Linux and windows dual-boot
Bluetooth is working in windows and at the same time when i boot up Kali `blootoothctl` it tells me that no default controller available what could be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

- The Bluetooth chip might be of a new model that is not yet supported by Linux
- The Bluetooth chip might be an OEM variant of an existing chip with a new product/vendor ID that is not yet known to Linux Bluetooth developers: this could be fixable by identifying the chip and e.g. adding some options for the appropriate kernel module to tell it to accept a new ID. If successful, it would be a good idea to report the new vendor/product ID to the developer of the corresponding kernel module, so that it can be made automatically known in future kernel versions.
- The Bluetooth chip might be supported and correctly identified, but it might require firmware loaded to it every time the chip is started up (many Broadcom Bluetooth chips have this requirement). If the firmware cannot be loaded, the chip will not work and the driver for it will not load successfully either. If you read the kernel messages using the `dmesg` command, you will see a message about a failed attempt to load a particular firmware file in this case.

Since Kali Linux is based on Debian, any non-Open-Source code - like firmware - is packaged separately and you must choose to install the appropriate firmware package. It might be `bluez-firmware` or something vendor-specific like `firmware-realtek`: you'll need to identify your Bluetooth chip and see if it is mentioned in the package descriptions.

If the Bluetooth chip is of a very new type, the firmware for it might not be included in the firmware packages yet. In that case, you will probably find it in the [linux-firmware Git repository](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/): just download the file indicated in the `dmesg` firmware download failure message, and place it into the appropriate directory under `/lib/firmware/` in your system.